# Add new panel inside parent panel in WP Customize?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

Is possible, add a panel within another panel.
example:
First Panel > child Panel > Section > First Setting
...
Second Panel > Section > First Setting
...

Answer (score 1):

Not possible as of now.

You can however achieve it by extending `WP_Customize_Panels` class.

Answer (score 1):

These days you can do it.

To all the developers who searched for an answer to that question and did not find one -

https://gist.github.com/foxpcteam/d2b44f1eda7d35f8b544dddf35b54643

create a file in your css main folder and name it pe-customize-controls.css
->  ( your_theme/css/pe-customize-controls.css )
paste that css :

```
.in-sub-panel #customize-theme-controls .customize-pane-child.current-panel-parent,
#customize-theme-controls .customize-pane-child.current-section-parent {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

create a file in your js main folder and name it pe-customize-controls.js
->  ( your_theme/js/pe-customize-controls.js )
paste that js :

```
( function( $ ) {

  var api = wp.customize;

  api.bind( 'pane-contents-reflowed', function() {

    // Reflow sections
    var sections = [];

    api.section.each( function( section ) {

      if (
        'pe_section' !== section.params.type ||
        'undefined' === typeof section.params.section
      ) {

        return;

      }

      sections.push( section );

    });

    sections.sort( api.utils.prioritySort ).reverse();

    $.each( sections, function( i, section ) {

      var parentContainer = $( '#sub-accordion-section-' + section.params.section );

      parentContainer.children( '.section-meta' ).after( section.headContainer );

    });

    // Reflow panels
    var panels = [];

    api.panel.each( function( panel ) {

      if (
        'pe_panel' !== panel.params.type ||
        'undefined' === typeof panel.params.panel
      ) {

        return;

      }

      panels.push( panel );

    });

    panels.sort( api.utils.prioritySort ).reverse();

    $.each( panels, function( i, panel ) {

      var parentContainer = $( '#sub-accordion-panel-' + panel.params.panel );

      parentContainer.children( '.panel-meta' ).after( panel.headContainer );

    });

  });


  // Extend Panel
  var _panelEmbed = wp.customize.Panel.prototype.embed;
  var _panelIsContextuallyActive = wp.customize.Panel.prototype.isContextuallyActive;
  var _panelAttachEvents = wp.customize.Panel.prototype.attachEvents;

  wp.customize.Panel = wp.customize.Panel.extend({
    attachEvents: function() {

      if (
        'pe_panel' !== this.params.type ||
        'undefined' === typeof this.params.panel
      ) {

        _panelAttachEvents.call( this );

        return;

      }

      _panelAttachEvents.call( this );

      var panel = this;

      panel.expanded.bind( function( expanded ) {

        var parent = api.panel( panel.params.panel );

        if ( expanded ) {

          parent.contentContainer.addClass( 'current-panel-parent' );

        } else {

          parent.contentContainer.removeClass( 'current-panel-parent' );

        }

      });

      panel.container.find( '.customize-panel-back' )
        .off( 'click keydown' )
        .on( 'click keydown', function( event ) {

          if ( api.utils.isKeydownButNotEnterEvent( event ) ) {

            return;

          }

          event.preventDefault(); // Keep this AFTER the key filter above

          if ( panel.expanded() ) {

            api.panel( panel.params.panel ).expand();

          }

        });

    },
    embed: function() {

      if (
        'pe_panel' !== this.params.type ||
        'undefined' === typeof this.params.panel
      ) {

        _panelEmbed.call( this );

        return;

      }

      _panelEmbed.call( this );

      var panel = this;
      var parentContainer = $( '#sub-accordion-panel-' + this.params.panel );

      parentContainer.append( panel.headContainer );

    },
    isContextuallyActive: function() {

      if (
        'pe_panel' !== this.params.type
      ) {

        return _panelIsContextuallyActive.call( this );

      }

      var panel = this;
      var children = this._children( 'panel', 'section' );

      api.panel.each( function( child ) {

        if ( ! child.params.panel ) {

          return;

        }

        if ( child.params.panel !== panel.id ) {

          return;

        }

        children.push( child );

      });

      children.sort( api.utils.prioritySort );

      var activeCount = 0;

      _( children ).each( function ( child ) {

        if ( child.active() && child.isContextuallyActive() ) {

          activeCount += 1;

        }

      });

      return ( activeCount !== 0 );

    }

  });


  // Extend Section
  var _sectionEmbed = wp.customize.Section.prototype.embed;
  var _sectionIsContextuallyActive = wp.customize.Section.prototype.isContextuallyActive;
  var _sectionAttachEvents = wp.customize.Section.prototype.attachEvents;

  wp.customize.Section = wp.customize.Section.extend({
    attachEvents: function() {

      if (
        'pe_section' !== this.params.type ||
        'undefined' === typeof this.params.section
      ) {

        _sectionAttachEvents.call( this );

        return;

      }

      _sectionAttachEvents.call( this );

      var section = this;

      section.expanded.bind( function( expanded ) {

        var parent = api.section( section.params.section );

        if ( expanded ) {

          parent.contentContainer.addClass( 'current-section-parent' );

        } else {

          parent.contentContainer.removeClass( 'current-section-parent' );

        }

      });

      section.container.find( '.customize-section-back' )
        .off( 'click keydown' )
        .on( 'click keydown', function( event ) {

          if ( api.utils.isKeydownButNotEnterEvent( event ) ) {

            return;

          }

          event.preventDefault(); // Keep this AFTER the key filter above

          if ( section.expanded() ) {

            api.section( section.params.section ).expand();

          }

        });

    },
    embed: function() {

      if (
        'pe_section' !== this.params.type ||
        'undefined' === typeof this.params.section
      ) {

        _sectionEmbed.call( this );

        return;

      }

      _sectionEmbed.call( this );

      var section = this;
      var parentContainer = $( '#sub-accordion-section-' + this.params.section );

      parentContainer.append( section.headContainer );

    },
    isContextuallyActive: function() {

      if (
        'pe_section' !== this.params.type
      ) {

        return _sectionIsContextuallyActive.call( this );

      }

      var section = this;
      var children = this._children( 'section', 'control' );

      api.section.each( function( child ) {

        if ( ! child.params.section ) {

          return;

        }

        if ( child.params.section !== section.id ) {

          return;

        }

        children.push( child );

      });

      children.sort( api.utils.prioritySort );

      var activeCount = 0;

      _( children ).each( function ( child ) {

        if ( 'undefined' !== typeof child.isContextuallyActive ) {

          if ( child.active() && child.isContextuallyActive() ) {

            activeCount += 1;

          }

        } else {

          if ( child.active() ) {

            activeCount += 1;

          }

        }

      });

      return ( activeCount !== 0 );

    }

  });

})( jQuery );
```

go to your functions.php page( or create a file call pre_customizer.php and include it inside functions.php), paste that code inside:

```
<?php

if ( class_exists( 'WP_Customize_Panel' ) ) {

  class PE_WP_Customize_Panel extends WP_Customize_Panel {

    public $panel;

    public $type = 'pe_panel';

    public function json() {

      $array = wp_array_slice_assoc( (array) $this, array( 'id', 'description', 'priority', 'type', 'panel', ) );
      $array['title'] = html_entity_decode( $this->title, ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) );
      $array['content'] = $this->get_content();
      $array['active'] = $this->active();
      $array['instanceNumber'] = $this->instance_number;

      return $array;

    }

  }

}

if ( class_exists( 'WP_Customize_Section' ) ) {

  class PE_WP_Customize_Section extends WP_Customize_Section {

    public $section;

    public $type = 'pe_section';

    public function json() {

      $array = wp_array_slice_assoc( (array) $this, array( 'id', 'description', 'priority', 'panel', 'type', 'description_hidden', 'section', ) );
      $array['title'] = html_entity_decode( $this->title, ENT_QUOTES, get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) );
      $array['content'] = $this->get_content();
      $array['active'] = $this->active();
      $array['instanceNumber'] = $this->instance_number;

      if ( $this->panel ) {

        $array['customizeAction'] = sprintf( 'Customizing &#9656; %s', esc_html( $this->manager->get_panel( $this->panel )->title ) );

      } else {

        $array['customizeAction'] = 'Customizing';

      }

      return $array;

    }

  }

}

// Enqueue our scripts and styles
function pe_customize_controls_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'pe-customize-controls', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/pe-customize-controls.js' ), array(), '1.0', true );

}

add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'pe_customize_controls_scripts' );

function pe_customize_controls_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'pe-customize-controls', get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/pe-customize-controls.css' ), array(), '1.0' );

}

add_action( 'customize_controls_print_styles', 'pe_customize_controls_styles' );

function pe_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

  // Has to be at the top
  $wp_customize->register_panel_type( 'PE_WP_Customize_Panel' );
  $wp_customize->register_section_type( 'PE_WP_Customize_Section' );


  // Below this there is only demo code, safe to delete and add your own
  // panels/sections/controls

  // Add three levels on panels
  $lvl1ParentPanel = new PE_WP_Customize_Panel( $wp_customize, 'lvl_1_parent_panel', array(
    'title' => 'Level 1',
    'priority' => 131,
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_panel( $lvl1ParentPanel );

  $lvl2ParentPanel = new PE_WP_Customize_Panel( $wp_customize, 'lvl_2_parent_panel', array(
    'title' => 'Level 2',
    'panel' => 'lvl_1_parent_panel',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_panel( $lvl2ParentPanel );

  $lvl3ParentPanel = new PE_WP_Customize_Panel( $wp_customize, 'lvl_3_parent_panel', array(
    'title' => 'Level 3',
    'panel' => 'lvl_2_parent_panel',
    'priority' => 1,
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_panel( $lvl3ParentPanel );

  // Add example section and controls to the final (third) panel
  $wp_customize->add_section( 'pe_section', array(
    'title' => 'Section Test',
    'panel' => 'lvl_3_parent_panel',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_setting( 'pe_test', array(
    'default' => 'default value here',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control( 'pe_test', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Some text control',
    'section' => 'pe_section',
  ));

  // Add example section and controls to the middle (second) panel
  $wp_customize->add_section( 'pe_section_2', array(
    'title' => 'Section 2 Test',
    'panel' => 'lvl_2_parent_panel',
    'priority' => 2,
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_setting( 'pe_test_2', array(
    'default' => 'default value here',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control( 'pe_test_2', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Some text control 2',
    'section' => 'pe_section_2',
  ));

  // Add example section and controls to another section
  $lvl1ParentSection = new PE_WP_Customize_Section( $wp_customize, 'lvl_1_parent_section', array(
    'title' => 'Level 1 Section',
    'panel' => 'lvl_3_parent_panel',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_section( $lvl1ParentSection );

  $lv21ParentSection = new PE_WP_Customize_Section( $wp_customize, 'lvl_2_parent_section', array(
    'title' => 'Level 2 Section',
    'section' => 'lvl_1_parent_section',
    'panel' => 'lvl_3_parent_panel',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_section( $lv21ParentSection );

  $wp_customize->add_setting( 'pe_test_3', array(
    'default' => 'default value here',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control( 'pe_test_3', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Some text control 3',
    'section' => 'lvl_2_parent_section',
  ));

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'pe_customize_register' );
```

then, if you go to your customizer you will see it

[image]

Hope I helped